# Dart binary search function is not working

Tags: algorithm, function, flutter, dart, binary-search

This is my function and it always returns -1. It prints right value of mid, but never returns it.

```
int binarySearch(List<int> arr, int userValue, int min, int max) {
    if (min >= 0) {
      int mid = ((max + min) / 2).floor();
      if (userValue == arr[mid]) {
        print(mid);
        return mid;
      } else if (userValue > arr[mid]) {
        binarySearch(arr, userValue, mid + 1, max);
      } else {
        binarySearch(arr, userValue, min, mid - 1);
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

Usage of function

```
int result = binarySearch(dates, 22, 0, 30);
```

Comment: you forgot to return the recusrsive calls

Comment: FYI, [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) provides a [`binarySearch` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/binarySearch.html)